# How to use tdfread to open txt files without a header?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to open txt files using the tdfread function in matlab. The resulting output structure has field names which are the data from the first row if the text.

Eg:
**Text file:**

1. NW  0   0
2. NW  1   2588
3. E_L 1   1760
4. E_L 1   1731
5. NW  1   1086
6. E_E 1   769
7. NE_L    1   984

.... 120 rows

**matlab output:**

```
field     value

x1        119x1 double

NE_E      119x4 char

x0        119x1 double

x01       119x1 double
```

I think the error is due to the fact that there is no header in the text file and the first line in the text file is considered as the header. Is there a way to fix this?

```
txt= tdfread('10091845_dat.txt', '\t');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, like you already suspected, this happens because of the missing header in the file. As a solution you can just add one to the top of your file, so that it looks like this:

```
col1 col2 col3
NW 0 0
NW 1 2588
E_L 1 1760
E_L 1 1731
NW 1 1086
E_E 1 769
NE_L 1 984

... more rows ...
```

If you really need to use `tdfread`, you can add this header line programmatically using `readtable` or using low-level IO functions (`fwrite`), where you have to read the data into memory first and then add the header and overwrite the file. Otherwise I'd advice to just use `readtable`, which saves all this stuff.

```
% using readtable
filename = 'file.txt';
d = readtable(filename, 'Delimiter', ' ')
d.Properties.VariableNames = {'col1', 'col2', 'col3'};
writetable(d, filename, 'Delimiter', ' ')
```

Since the data is read into a table datastructure, which features column names by default, `writetable` also writes these names as header into the file, so all that's left to do, is setting the desired column names, instead of the default.

```
% using low level IO
filename = 'file.txt';
data = fileread(filename);
data = ['col1 col2 col3', newline, data];
FID = fopen(filename, 'w');
if(FID == -1)
    error('Cannot open file %s', filename);
end
fwrite(FID, data, 'char');
fclose(FID);
```

And since you seem to be using spaces and not tabs as delimiters in your file you can also change that:

```
tdfread('file.txt', ' ');
```